# How to use autoload?

Tags: libraries

I am trying to figure out how to add autoload features to a private library. Let's say I have developed a private Lisp library `"my-lib.el"`. It consist of a set of functions, some can be used from any mode, others are only used for a particular mode. According to the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Autoload.html) I could put a autoload cookie above each function definition, and then call `update-file-autoloads`. Is this correct? But when do I call `update-file-autoloads`? In the beginning of the Emacs init file?

For example, in my `~/.emacs` init file, I could write:

```el
(update-file-autoloads "my-lib.el")
(require 'my-lib)
```

Where in `"my-lib.el"`

```el
;;;###autoload
(defun my-func()
  (interactive)
  (message "Hello")) 

;;; more functions, omitted here...

(provide 'my-lib)
```

But this gives error from `update-file-autoloads` if the file is not in the current directory. Or if `"my-lib.el"` is in the current directory, I get the error: `Wrong type argument: stringp, nil`.

My aim is to be able to type `M-x my-func` (as an example), and `my-func` should autoload at that point if this was the first time I called it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not how I would do it. I would:

1. `update-file-autoloads` for `"my-lib.el"` to `"my-lib-autoloads.el"`.
2. `(require 'my-lib-autoloads)` in `"init.el"`.

That's it. Now, each time you add or remove an autoload cookie, you should update `"my-lib-autoloads.el"`.
Don't parse `"my-lib.el"` at startup: it's probably slower than just loading it.

Comment: Thanks @abo-abo. But why do I get error: `Wrong type argument: stringp, nil` from `update-file-autoloads` ? According to `C-h f update-file-autoloads` the syntax is: `(update-file-autoloads FILE &optional SAVE-AFTER OUTFILE)` .. and what is the purpose of the `SAVE-AFTER` argument?

Comment: I did the thing interactively. The following code also works: `(update-file-autoloads "lispy.el" t (expand-file-name "lispy-autoloads.el"))`

Comment: `SAVE-AFTER` will save the "-autoloads.el" file if it's already open, I guess.

Comment: Ok, I see.. But now this produces a file `"my-lib-autoloads.el"` with only one statement `"(provide 'my-lib-autoloads)`".. Shouldn't there be some `autoload` statements in there too?

Comment: Do you have `;;;###autoload` in the file?

Comment: Yes, I have. To debug, I used a file that is identical to the one shown in the Question above..

Comment: I think I found the problem. It seems like `update-file-autoloads` creates a new buffer with `"my-lib-autoloads.el"`, but it does not save the buffer to the file with the same name. That was what confused me, since I looked at the file, and not the buffer :).. Wonder, why it does not save the buffer by default?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `package.el`, after changing `my-lib.el` every time, use `package-install-from-buffer` to install your private library as a package. You don't need to issue `(require 'my-lib)` in your init file for invoking autoload commands because `package.el` has already generated `"my-lib-autoloads.el"` and loaded it for you.