# How does Emacs see the generated autoloads files?

Tags: package, autoload, load-path

I have some of my own Elisp code in my own directory. Like I have a file `/tmp/foo/foo.el` with this in it:

```lisp
;;; foo.el -- Foo

;;;###autoload
(defun foo-hello ()
  (message "hello, world"))

(provide 'foo)

;;; foo.el ends here
```

I open Emacs and run `M-x make-directory-autoloads RET /tmp/foo/foo-autoloads.el RET`.

Then I add this to my `~/.emacs.d/init.el`:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'load-path "/tmp/foo/")
(foo-hello)
```

Then I start Emacs but I get this error:

```
eval-buffer: Symbol’s function definition is void: foo-hello
```

What did I miss? How do I make Emacs see my generate autoloads file and use it to automatically load the autoloads when I use them? Is there an extra step involved?

If there is an extra step involved, then how does Emacs automatically see the autoloads installed with package manager. Like I never did anything special to make Emacs recognize `~/.emacs.d/elpa/magit-20230402.1342/magit-autoloads.el`. How does Emacs see that file automatically but it does not see my autoloads file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use autoload?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/8023/how-to-use-autoload)

Comment: @Y.E. That does not seem to answer my question. The current answer here and in your link too involve a `require`. But when I install a package from MELPA, I don't have to do any `require` for them. When I call any autoloaded function from those packages, the package gets "required" automatically. So I want to know how Emacs packages installed from MELPA get autoloaded without any `require`?

Comment: The package system does the `require`  (actually a `load`, but that comes to the same thing) for you: it gathers up a list of packages under your `~/.emacs.d/elpa` directory (or equivalent) and loops over them. For each one, it `load`s the autoload file for the package, thereby making its autoloaded functions available to you. See the function `package-activate-1` and the line that reads `(load (package--autoloads-file-name pkg-desc) nil t))`. Apart from the minor `require` vs `load`, it's exactly what the answer below and the duplicate question describe.

Comment: That's what happens when you start `emacs` after having installed some packages. When you install a package in a running Emacs session, the `package-activate-1` function is called by the installation code explicitly, thereby adding that package's autoloads in the same way.

Comment: See [Packaging Basics](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Packaging-Basics.html) in the Emacs Lisp Reference manual.

Comment: If this happens when your init file is loaded, is it normal that the error message comes from `eval-buffer`? Are you sure just starting Emacs, with only your init file as shown (nothing else loaded) produces exactly that error message, with `eval-buffer: `?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no magic with files of autoload declarations -- just like any other `*.el` file, Emacs knows nothing about the contents of an `*-autoloads.el` file unless that file is `load`ed; so in order to make Emacs process your file you will need to load it explicitly.

> I never did anything special to make Emacs recognize `~/.emacs.d/elpa/magit-20230402.1342/magit-autoloads.el`. How does Emacs see that file automatically but it does not see my autoloads file?

Simply because the package manager in Emacs explicitly loaded that file as part of its `package-initialize` activities.

In 28.2 that looks like this:

```el
(defun package--autoloads-file-name (pkg-desc)
  "Return the absolute name of the autoloads file, sans extension.
PKG-DESC is a `package-desc' object."
  (expand-file-name
   (format "%s-autoloads" (package-desc-name pkg-desc))
   (package-desc-dir pkg-desc)))

(defun package--activate-autoloads-and-load-path (pkg-desc)
  "Load the autoloads file and add package dir to `load-path'.
PKG-DESC is a `package-desc' object."
  (let* ((old-lp load-path)
         (pkg-dir (package-desc-dir pkg-desc))
         (pkg-dir-dir (file-name-as-directory pkg-dir)))
    (with-demoted-errors "Error loading autoloads: %s"
      (load (package--autoloads-file-name pkg-desc) nil t))
    (when (and (eq old-lp load-path)
               (not (or (member pkg-dir load-path)
                        (member pkg-dir-dir load-path))))
      ;; Old packages don't add themselves to the `load-path', so we have to
      ;; do it ourselves.
      (push pkg-dir load-path))))
```

ELPA packages follow conventions, and so such things can be done automatically.  Emacs can't make any guesses about your custom code though, so you need to do it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure how Emacs usually does this, but you should simply `require` the autoloads before calling `(foo-hello)`, using `(require 'foo-autoloads)`.

Now instead of loading the full foo 'package' directly, Emacs initially only loads the autoload definitions, and then of course loads `foo` only when calling `(foo-hello)`.

Answer (score 1):

In your "foo-autoloads.el" generated by `make-directory-autoloads`, you will see the line:

```lisp
(autoload 'foo-hello "foo" nil nil nil)
```

Why not just write this one line directly to `init.el`? (without even generating "foo-autoloads.el").
Since your "foo.el" is ready to be auto-loaded, it may be sufficient to write a very general autoloading configuration `(autoload 'foo-hello "foo")`, without 3 nil parameters, in `init.el` unless you want to autoload everything (multiple files besides "foo.el") under your "foo" directory at once.

Comment: Your addition (from "And the answer ...")  is barking up the wrong tree: `loaddefs.el` or `ldef-boot.el`  is an autoload file that's produced when Emacs is built: it contains the autoloads for all the built-in stuff. It does not contain anything about packages installed from ELPA/MELPA (like `magit`). See @phil's answer (for 28.2 - and my comment above for current upstream Emacs) for how that is done.

Comment: @NickD: I think I am aware of the same thing, but if it appears to be clearly misinformation from an Emacs hacker NickD's view, I will remove it. I meant to write that the `lisp/loaddefs.el` which is pre-prepared and does not contain user-selected packages as you point out, loads them dynamically through `(custom-autoload 'package-user-dir "package" t)` in the quoted source above.

Comment: That's wrong: all that that does is autoload the `package` module. It does not do anything with the installed ELPA/MELPA packages.

Comment: @NickD: Roger, I erased the wrong part. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've written tons of Emacs packages and it was a nightmare to ensure that the generated autoload:s were up to date. Also, I didn't want to install the packages since I would end up having two copies of each source file, one in the source location and one in `.emacs.d/elpa`.

Instead, I came up with the following code that sits in my init file. It allows me to point to the source file and let Emacs synthesise autoload:s from the `###autoload` constructs.

```
;; ----------------------------------------
;; Silence messages.
;;

(defvar my--silence-messages nil)


(defadvice message (around my-message activate)
  (unless my--silence-messages
    ad-do-it))


(defmacro my-with-silent-messages (&rest body)
  "Like `progn' but silence messages emitted by talky functions."
  `(let ((my--silence-messages t))
     ,@body))


;; ----------------------------------------
;; On the fly autoloads.
;;
;; Apply the ";;;###autoload" construct of a file. Mainly used for
;; packages written by me to avoid having to install them using the
;; package manager, while still taking advantage of the autoload
;; annotations.

(defun my-autoload-onthefly (file &optional dir add-to-load-path)
  "Create autoloads on the fly for FILE.

If DIR is specified, FILE is expected to be relative it.

Add DIR to `load-path'. If ADD-TO-LOAD-PATH is non-nil, add the
full path of FILE to `load-path'."
  (require 'autoload)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (unless dir
      (setq dir (file-name-directory file)))
    (add-to-list 'load-path dir :append)
    (let ((path (concat dir file)))
      (when (or add-to-load-path
                ;; For some reason, `generate-file-name' does not
                ;; include any part of the path in older Emacs
                ;; versions.
                (version< emacs-version "24.0"))
        (add-to-list 'load-path (file-name-directory path)))
      (my-with-silent-messages
       (let ((buffer-file-name (concat dir "dummy.el")))
         (generate-file-autoloads path)))
      (eval-buffer))
    ;; Return content of temp buffer, to help debugging.
    (buffer-string)))
```

Also in my init file:

```
(my-autoload-onthefly "~/emacs/src/font-lock-studio/font-lock-studio.el")
```